# java NullPointerException in camera plugin for cordova after adding proguard

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-camera, cordova-plugins

I am trying to add Proguard to my ionic cordova project. Every thing is working fine except the `take_picture` method of camera cordova plugin. The proguard rules are mostly added by trial and error method so there can be a mistake which I am not able to see so if anyone who has experience of dealing with proguard can help, that would be great.

Here are my proguard rules-

```
-keep class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService


-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}




-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Enable proguard with Cordova
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin


-keep class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader { java.lang.ClassLoader sClassLoader; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor { int MODULE_VERSION; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags.ModuleDescriptor { java.lang.String MODULE_ID; }

-keep class org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }
-keep class org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }
-keep class org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }
-keep class org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }
-keep class org.apache.cordova.ResumeCallback { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }
-keep class org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }

-keep class com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator { ** theUnsafe; }
-keep class me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger { ** extraNotification; }
-keep class me.leolin.shortcutbadger.impl.XiaomiHomeBadger { ** messageCount; }
-keep class me.leolin.shortcutbadger.impl.XiaomiHomeBadger { ** extraNotification; }

-dontnote org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto
-dontnote sun.misc.Unsafe

-keep class com.worklight.androidgap.push.** { *; }
-keep class com.worklight.wlclient.push.** { *; }

# Enable proguard with Google libs
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**



-keep class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }
-dontwarn net.sqlcipher.**

-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Remove debug logs in release build
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}

# These classes contain references to external jars which are not included in the default MobileFirst project.
-dontwarn com.worklight.common.internal.WLTrusteerInternal*
-dontwarn com.worklight.jsonstore.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.*
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.push.GCMIntentService
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLInitializationPlugin

-keep class  android.**
-dontwarn android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
-dontwarn android.net.http.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class android.support.v4.content
-dontwarn org.apache.**

#-keep class org.** { *; }
```

Any help will be great, waiting for a positive reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is still stuck on this

Add this line to Your proguard rules

```
-keep class com.abc.xyz.BuildConfig { *; }
```

where com.abc.xyz is your Package name

that's it ......

thank me later...

happy coding